# how to remove two forward slashes in a comment with sed

Tags: sed

I have a configuration file and I want to replace a line containing a specific string,  lets say *test* :

file.conf

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
// test
ddd
// test
```

My line of code is not working, I'm new to  **sed**.

```
sed -i `s#^//[ \t]test#test#g'
```

Some guidance ?

Comment: its an interesting question - any reason why you wish to delete this?

Comment: I'm working on a script that automatically configures and installs lamp so I need to uncomment two lines in phpmyadmin conf file to accept nopasswd login via the web interface.

Comment: @pyn Consider using tools designed specifically for deploying applications instead: Puppet, Juju, Chef, etc. Writing your own scripts to deploy applications is usually reinventing wheels and/or axles.

Comment: I'm doing this for learning purposes, to get familiar with bash scripting ( CLI ).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, I'd recommend to avoid the use of `-i` as it will replace the files in-place without confirmation.

This is a working version of what you were trying to accomplish and outputs to the standard output (the terminal):

```
sed 's#^//[ \t]test$#test#g' file.conf
aaa
bbb
ccc
test
ddd
test
```

Optionally pipe it through less by appending `| less` to be able to paginate through large amounts of output.

The above is all very specific to the sequence of `test`, so to more generalize, you can try this:

```
sed 's#^//\s\(.*\)$#\1#g' file.conf
```

It will remove the `//` part and any whitespace until the actual text, whatever this text is.

If you like the result, you can add the `-i` flag again to replace the file.

---

To tell more about your attempt and explain why my example does work:

```
sed -i `s#^//[ \t]test#test#g'
```

- You are using a backtick (`) which is interpreted by your shell rather than Sed. A simple single quote (`'`) should have been used here probably.
- The hashes (`#`) are your chosen delimiter, a good alternative to the common forward slash (`/`) as your match is about this same character and this avoids the need for escaping.
- The pattern in the command `s/regexp/replacement/` is a standard one as mentioned in the manpage, among many others: `man 1 sed`:

  > `s/regexp/replacement/`
  >
  > Attempt to match regexp against the pattern
  >   space. If successful, replace that portion matched with replacement.
  >   The replacement may contain the special character `&` to refer to that
  >   portion of the pattern space which matched, and the special escapes
  >   `\1` through `\9` to refer to the corresponding matching
  >   sub-expressions in the regexp.
- `rexexp` in the above is a commonly used abbreviation for [*regular expressions*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression).
- The regular expression `^//[ \t]test$` matches lines starting (`^`) with two forward slashes, followed by a space *or* a tab character, followed by the exact sequence `test` and a line ending (`$`).
- The `g` flag is to do this operation in a global way as explained [here](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-6).
- An input file is missing and should be given after the Sed-command.

Comment: 1. backtick, I miss typed
2. I was thinking to use a different delimiter fo clarity purposes
3. Yes, I know.

Answer (score 2):

You do **not** have to use forward slashes as separator. In fact, I recommend using other separators like comma or hashes for readability.

`-i` is also your friend, but only use it if you know for sure it is correct. In this case, I would do something like:

```
sed -r 's,^//[ \t]*(.+),\1,' file.conf | less
```

I use `-r` here for extended regexp, so I do not have to escape the parentheses. Furthermore, it allows me to use the plus operator which means "one or more occurrences". The following expression would be equivalent:

```
sed 's,^//[ \t]*\(..*\),\1,' file.conf | less
```

(one dot to match at least one character followed by zero or more of any character)

After I am sure that the replacement is correct (type slash followed by your keywords in `less` for searching), I close less by typing `q` and navigate to the previous history entry by pressing the Up key. I then delete `| less` and type `-i` to proceed with the replacement:

```
sed -r 's,^//[ \t]*(.+),\1,' file.conf -i
```

If you want to gain a deeper understanding of sed, I can recommend you reading the info page of sed which is more extended than the manual page:

```
info sed
```

Comment: I didn't know about the use of alternative delimiters. Thanks - I was wrong in my answer apparently - fixed that now. :)

Comment: This^ is what I said above.:)